# Can I use something else instead of "this" in this code?

Tags: c#, events, this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Event_training
{
    class Publisher
    {
        public event EventHandler x;

        public void raise()
        {
            x(this, null);
        }

    }

    class Subscriber
    {
        public void method1(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("metod1 called");
        }

        public void method2(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("metod2 called");
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Publisher p = new Publisher();
            Subscriber s = new Subscriber();

            p.x += s.method1;
            p.x += s.method2;

            p.raise();
        }
    }
}
```

Having hard time to understrand "this" keyword. What does it refer to "x(this, null);" in here? Can I use something else instead of "this"?

Comment: Please read [this (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) and close question

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance of `Publisher`.

Comment: Why am I giving its instance to its method?

Comment: How can we know why you do that?

Comment: @Lyrk `x` is an `EventHandler` which takes a `sender` (what raised the event), your class instance in this case, and `EventArgs` which you've passed as null. If you're asking why you are doing this in particular, only you can answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to pass instance of `Publisher`? Assume you have several publishers and one subscriber:

```
 Publisher p1 = new Publisher() { Name = "Bob" };
 Publisher p2 = new Publisher() { Name = "Joe" };
 Subscriber s = new Subscriber();
```

You subscribe to `x` event of both publishers:

```
 p1.x += s.method1;
 p2.x += s.method1;
```

Now question - how you will know which publisher raised event in event handle?

```
public void method1(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("metod1 called");
}
```

That's why default `EventHandler` delegate has two parameters. First one is usually called `sender` instead of `o`. So that you will be able to check `sender` and understand which publisher raised event. Assume `Publisher` has also `Name` property:

```
class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler x;
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    public void Raise()
    {
       EventHandler x = this.x;
       if (x != null)
          x(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now in event handler you can get name of publisher, because you have passed publisher instance (`this`) to even handler:

```
public void method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Publisher publisher = (Publisher)sender;
    Console.WriteLine(publisher.Name + " raised event x");
}
```

If you don't need to pass any event args and instance of object which raised event, then you can use other type of delegate for event. E.g. [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate do not have any parameters.

```
class Publisher
{
    public event Action x;      

    public void Raise()
    {
       Action x = this.x;
       if (x != null)
          x(); // No parameters
    }
}
```

And handler will look like:

```
public void method1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("metod1 called");
}
```

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer. I think I get it now.

Comment: @Lyrk good :) As Dmitry said, usage of `EventHandler` delegates is kind of standard and it started from `WinForms` development. Some guys in Microsoft decided that you always will need to know sender of event. And implemented this `EventHandler` approach through all `WinForms` system. Any events (button clicks, hiding/showing controls etc) is implemented via EventHandler delegates. But you are not restricted here and you can use whatever delegate type you want. But my recommendation - do not mix different approaches.

Comment: Sometimes these shortcuts microsoft developers created cause hard time for people to understand who do not know past implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Standard pattern is

```
// it's not a public method 
internal void raise()
{
    // local copy for being thread safe
    var localX = x;

    // do not forget to check for null
    if (null != localX)
      localX(this, EventArgs.Empty); // standard EventArgs.Empty, not null
}
```

Note, that `this` is a *part of the standard pattern*: it shows *which* instance (i.e. `this`) raises the event.

Comment: ...or `x?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)` using c# 6.

Comment: What do you mean by standard pattern? You meant standard usage?

Comment: @Lyrk: *standard pattern* in the context is a typical, recommended implemenation, i.e. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current instant of the class.

For example:

```
Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
publisher.raise();
```

Where `this` is the `publisher` instance in this case. Maybe it is more clear if I show it to you like:
`publisher.x(publisher, null);`

Also, in your case the first parameter isn't even used. So you can also write `null, null`.

The `object o` as you call it, is normally called `sender`. Which makes sense, because whatever object that raises the event, is passed through this parameter.

If you want to learn more about the `this` keyword, refer to the microsoft site ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dk1507sz.aspx))

Comment: For example in above code, I created an instance of Publisher class named "p" in main. "this" refers to "p" then. Is this true?

Comment: `this` is just the current instance. If there is a `this` keyword inside a method. Then the `this` keyword refers to `p` in your case. Where if you have multiple instances of `Publisher` they all reference to the correct instance. Like: `Publisher p = new Publisher(); Publisher pub = new Publisher();`. Where the `this` keyword inside `raise` is equal to the instance calling the method. Like: `this` is `pub` when doing `pub.raise()` and `this` is `p` doing `p.raise()`

Comment: thanks for the answer.